# traverse back in php from a specific keyword or position

Tags: php

I want to find the string from

```
$str = "Hello this is dummy.test. in this string  
any character, any special character can appear. it is not a fixed type 
text and predefined. this string will not read manually check by the 
Programmer.Sorry for the bad English.";
```

my algo is fixed because some kind of problem.
First I want to find the position of **test** keyword then want to go back from **test** to **dummy** keyword to find position of **dummy** keyword .

I also searched and also use the internet but no any function found in PHP which can traverse back in this way.

I also test `strrpos()` but not relevant and required result.
Any solution please.

**Output needed** : **dummy.test**

**Algo** : **find first right (test) and then right to left (dummy) only. not first right (test) and then from starting to left (dummy) .**

Comment: let me update question with more clear .

Comment: Use strops() to find the position(s) of "test"; then substring() and strops() for "dummy" in the substring

Answer (score 1):

First find the position of `test` using [`strpos()`](http://php.net/strpos), cut the string up until `test` with [`substr()`](http://php.net/substr), and then use [`strpos()`](http://php.net/strpos) again to find the position of `dummy` in the substring:

```
$substring = substr($str, 0, strpos($str, 'test'));
$dummy = strpos($substring, 'dummy');
echo $dummy;
```

Output:

```
14
```

[**Demo!**](http://codepad.org/oMOpesxI)

---

**UPDATE**

As per the question edit, the following function should do what you want. It's probably not the best solution and is a bit ugly, but that should get you started:

```
function searchstr($str) 
{
    $pos = strpos($str, 'test') + strlen($str);
    $substring = substr($str, 0, $pos);
    $dummypos = strpos($substring, 'dummy', TRUE);

    $words = explode(' ', $str);
    $chars = -1; 
    foreach($words as $word)
    {
      $chars += strlen($word);
      if($chars >= $dummypos)
      {
         return $word;
      }   
    }   
    return ''; 
}   

echo searchStr($str);
```

Output:

```
dummy.test.
```

[**Demo!**](http://codepad.org/SMWoGi5b)

Comment: Sorry not near to my solution. why are you getting $substring  and then again search for dummy from starting. if dummy.test is on 10000 position then ?? your code taking too more space and time. both should be reduce.

Comment: @JohnHarper: You didn't state that in your question. Are you trying to search from the right side of the string?

Comment: i just want to search from right (test)  to left (dummy) only. not from right then from start to left.

Comment: @JohnHarper: What's the expected output?

Comment: Output needed : dummy.test   please look at my question is updated

Answer (score 0):

`strrpos` Would be the right way. If I understand you correctly, this should work, using the offset parameter:

```
$test = strrpos($str, 'test');
$dummy = strrpos($str, 'dummy', $test);
```

This will find the last "dummy" that occurs before the last "test".